# How to activate new v2 newsletter design in Connections CR5

Tags: ibm-connections, hcl

We recently updated Connections CR4 to CR5. Before the update, the new newsletter design was enabled by setting

```
<property name="globalNotificationTemplateTheme">notifications_v2</property>
```

in the `<property>` section of `notification-config.xml` file. After the update, this was still set to `notifications_v2` but doesn't work. I get the old newsletter design.

What is required to enable the new v2 design in CR5? Couldn't find documentations or changelogs from IBM about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using CR5, you also need to set this property in the `<properties>` section:

```
<property name="globalNotificationTemplateThemeEnable">true</property>
```

This is also mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYGQH_6.0.0/admin/admin/t_admin_common_enable_template.html):

> 4. IMPORTANT: The CR5 update also adds a new property, globalNotificationTemplateThemeEnable, that must now be set to true, even if you already enabled the enhanced templates during CR4.